# Induction Proof: $(x+1)^n > nx^2+1$

Tags: induction

Prove the following statement using induction.

> If $x > 1$ is a real number, then $(x+1)^n > nx^2+1$ for all $n \ge 3$.

[image]

Comment: Ways to improve your question: 1) Ask questions one at a time, 2) Make the effort to write the question here rather than simply posting a link to a picture, 3) Don't just post homework here without any thoughts/efforts of your own, 4) Write a more informative title. Your last question also get heavily downvoted and closed because of this.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit your question so that there is just one question (not 8), included as text (not an image) and if you show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I forgot to write down which one when I realized it I couldn’t change it

Comment: @josebravo You can edit the question. Please also include some text about where you are stuck.

Comment: How do I edit ? I’m new to this

Comment: There is a button beneath the question, but above the comments. It is in line with where your name is.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Try to first do it to $n=3$. Then suppose it is valid for $n$ and do it for $n = n+3$. Then you should find a way to simplify it and get your answer.

Comment: To replace that photograph with just the question you meant to ask, in a legible mathematical format, start with the advice here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Side note: l liked the problem 2! It is a lovely problem to which induction can be applied as well.

Answer (score 1):

I leave the base case $n=3$ to you.

Note that you need to prove that $$(x+1)^n>nx^2+1 .$$
Suppose $$(x+1)^k >kx^2+1$$ for some $k \ge 3$. Then
$$(x+1)^{k+1}=(x+1)(x+1)^k >(x+1)(kx^2+1)=kx^3+x+kx^2+1.$$
Next, we consider $kx^3+x > x^2 \iff kx^2-x+1>0 \iff 1-4k <0$, which is true.

Therefore, 
$$(x+1)^{k+1}>kx^3+x+kx^2+1>x^2+kx^2+1=(k+1)x^2+1.$$

---

The expression $ax^2+bx+c > 0$ when $a >0$ and $b^2-4ac < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

First verify it for $n=3$:

$(x+1)^3 > 3x^2 +1 $

$(x+1)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x+1 = x^3+3x +( 3x^2 +1) > 3x^2+1$

$x^3+3x >0$, which is true, since $x>1$.

Suppose it holds for $n$. 
Now check for $n=n+3$:

$(x+1)^{n+3} > (n+3)x^2 +1 $

$(x+1)^n (x+1)^3 > nx^2+3x^2 +1 $

$\frac{(x+1)^n (x+1)^3}{(x+1)^n } > \frac{nx^2+1}{(x+1)^n } + \frac{3x^2}{(x+1)^n }$

$ (x+1)^3 > \frac{nx^2+1}{(x+1)^n } + \frac{3x^2}{(x+1)^n } $

But, since by hypothesis $(x+1)^n > nx^2 +1  \Rightarrow 1>\frac{nx^2+1}{(x+1)^n }$ and also  $3x^2 > \frac{3x^2}{(x+1)^n} $

Thus:

$ (x+1)^3 > 3x^2+1 > \frac{3x^2}{(x+1)^n } + \frac{nx^2+1}{(x+1)^n }$

Which is true, since it is valid for $n=3$

Answer (score 0):

$(x + 1)^{n+1} = (x+1)^n*(x+1) > (nx^2 + 1)(x+1) = nx^3 + nx^2 + x + 1$.

$(n+1)x^2 + 1= nx^2 + x^2 + 1$

Which of those two are larger?